# Gerrit / Jenkins on same / different servers

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I'm setting up a 'proof of concept' Gerrit & jenkins workflow for potential network management automation use at work. 
Should I set up Jenkins and Gerrit on the same server or separate servers? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proof of concept, you could use the same server.
For production, I would recommend different ones, esp. if the load caused by creating the builds is very high.